# jquery-ui autocomplete does not display utf-8 correct

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, character-encoding, mysqli

I have run into some problems with displaying data in jquery ui autocomplete, when i display the text, it is not utf-8 encoded, despite my db and page are using utf-8.

Also when i try to display it any other way, it show normally with the right encoding.

**The jquery ui script.**

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(function() {
    function log( message ) {
        $( "<div>" ).text( message ).prependTo( "#log" );
        $( "#log" ).scrollTop( 0 );
    }

    $( "#items" ).autocomplete({
        source: "getSurgestedItems.php",
        minLength: 2,
        select: function( event, ui ) {
            log( ui.item ?
                "Selected: " + ui.item.value + " aka " + ui.item.id :
                "Nothing selected, input was " + this.value );
        }
    }).data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item){
        return $("<li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a>" + item.value + "<br>" + item.desc + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    };
});
</script>
```

**The php script getting the items.**

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
$i++;
if(!$first){
    $json .=',';
}
else{
    $first = false;
}

$name = addslashes($row['name']);
$desc = mb_substr(addslashes($row['description']), 0, 60, 'UTF-8');

$desc .= '...';

$json .='{"value" : "'.$name.'",
        "desc" : "'.$desc.'"}';
}
$json .=']';

echo $json;
```

Now like i said I have tried to displaying the data, in every way i can think of and it is only with the autocomplete feature it is displayed wrong.

Comment: You should use [json_encode](http://de1.php.net/json_encode) to properly format your return data: `echo json_encode(array('value' => $name, 'desc' => $desc));` which should handle escaping the data for you.

Comment: RobAu - it is in all browsers available to me amt, chrome, ff and ie.

saschaM78 - tried with json_encode, and it does the escaping fine but now I just wont display the part with the "illegal" chars, before I would get a black square with a "?" inside, now it just says null.

Comment: @saschaM78 - Thanks you post got me looking in the right direction, see my answer for details.

Comment: Great it worked! Could you mark your post as answer so others may see how you solved it? Thx

Comment: Have to wait 2 days before i can accept my own answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SaschaM78 comment got me looking in the right direction, while looking into json_encode, I discovered that it would only work with utf-8, which led me to try and encode each string to utf-8, using **mb_convert_encoding**, which have solve my problem, it works fine now.

**The new php code.**

```
$json = array();

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

$name = mb_convert_encoding($row['name'], 'UTF-8');
$desc = mb_convert_encoding(substr($row['description'], 0, 60), 'UTF-8');

$desc .= '...';

$json[] = array('value' => $name, 'desc' => $desc); 
}

echo json_encode($json);
```